# vba: How can I change the name of a new added workbook in an inactive worksheet?

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

```
With Swkbook.Worksheets("SalesRecords")

For intIndex = 1 To .Range("D1", .Range("D1048576").End(xlUp)).Rows.Count - 1

strNewName = .Range("d2").Offset(intIndex - 1, 0).Value

Namesexist = False

For Each wksheet In Nwkbook.Worksheets

            If VBA.LCase(strNewName) = VBA.LCase(wksheet.Name) Then
               Namesexist = True
           End If
        Next wksheet

        If namesexits = False Then
         Set WS = Nwkbook.Worksheets.Add
         Worksheets(WS).Name = strNewName
        End If
 Next intIndex
 End With
```

I am working on a active workbook called "abc" and there are two another workbook called "S" and "N".

Now I want to let the D rows value in S to be the name of each new worksheet in N (without repeat)

The above are my code, however, this statement get error:

```
   Worksheets(WS).Name = strNewName
```

> Type mismatch.

May you help me to solve the problem? Thanks you.

---

I have declared the variable before the with statement:

```
Dim intIndex As Integer
Dim strNewName As String
Dim Namesexist As Boolean
```

but I now get another error:
[image]

which is from:

```
WS.Name = strNewName
```

Comment: Okay, so is there another sheet already that has the same name? Try stepping through your code in debug mode and watching how your variables evolve ([instructions](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx)). If that doesn't help, then I suggest you see this for guidance: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After this line gets executed

```
Set WS = Nwkbook.Worksheets.Add
```

`WS` is a Worksheet object that contains a reference to that new worksheet you just added. You can then change its name like this:

```
WS.Name = strNewName
```

In fact, I advise you to declare your variables properly using  `Dim`

```
Dim WS As Worksheet
```

This is a good idea for million different reasons, one of which is that you can then use autocomplete to easily see what you can do with your object:

[image]

Comment: thanks you. and I have actually declared the variable but still got error. you may see my edition of the problem :(